# User Notifications - How to recover a lost notification_id from GCM?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I generate `notification_key`s as described [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html#gen-server).

Suppose that due to some error I fail to store it, so I try to re-register.
This time I receive a 400 error with the message `"notification_key already exists"`.
This looks odd, especially compared to [registration of a device to GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html#sample-register), where you can register as many times as you want and always get the same Registration ID with status 200.
Now I can't register again, and I also can't unregister, because I don't have the `notification_id`.

Is there any way to get the previously generated `notification_key` from GCM?
Or is the only way to register again with a different `notification_key_name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the docs, there is no way to get from GCM the `notification_key` of an existing `notification_key_name`. If you think about it, it makes sense that trying to create a new `notification_key` for an existing `notification_key_name` would give you an error, since if it wasn't the case, you might be accidentally overwriting the Registration IDs of an existing `notification_key` if you happen to supply an existing `notification_key_name` by mistake.

You are comparing this to registering a device to GCM multiple times, each time getting the same Registration ID, but it's not a similar situation. When you register a device to GCM, GCM has a way to identify the device and know that it is already registered and return the same Registration ID. With user notifications, it only has the `notification_key_name` that you supplied, and there's nothing stopping you from using the same `notification_key_name` for multiple users. That is, there is something stopping you - the error you got when trying to create a `notification_key` with a previously used `notification_key_name`.

An easy way to overcome your problem is to treat `notification_key_name` as a unique identifier generated by your server. If you don't have a `notification_key` for a certain user (either because it's a new user or because you failed to store the `notification_key` you previously got from Google), you generate a new unique `notification_key_name` and use it to create a new `notification_key`. You don't have to care about the old `notification_key` that you failed to store.

Finally you store both the `notification_key` and `notification_key_name` in a table that contains the user id.

Comment: It makes sense to get an error, but it doesn't make sense that you then can't retrieve the one they already know about...  If they can identify a duplicate, they could provide an interface to return it... As you suggest making the `notification_key_name` generated by my server, it means the generated `notification_key_name` won't be one-to-one with the app's username, which makes things needlessly complicated if I could just retrieve the `notification_key`...

Comment: @xbakesx Your notification_key_name would still be one-to-one with the app's usernames. If you generate a notification_key_name in order to obtain a notification_key from Google, and fail to persist the notification_key, you won't persist the notfiication_key_name either. Then you would generate a new notification_key_name (for a given username) in order to obtain a new notification_key, and that would be the only notification_key_name associated with the username in your DB.

Answer (score 8):

I can't find any documentation about it but it's now possible to recover a `notification_key` for a device group by doing a `GET` request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification?notification_key_name=my_notification_key_name with the headers they require: `Authorization: key=my_key`, `Content-Type: application/json` and `project_id: my_id`.

You will get a response like  `{
  "notification_key": "lost_key"
}`

But be aware that returned notification_key is not the same as original, but you can use both of them.

Comment: This works for me, thanks! I can't believe how bad the documentation is...

Comment: Adopters of this solution, be double-aware that `Content-Type: application/json` is actually required for no apparent reason, it does not make sense in that context.
On the other hand, it works.

Answer (score -1):

If you happen to know all the registered registration ids in the device group. Then delete them all and the device group will be deleted too. Afterwards you can create a device group with the before used notification_key_name.

Comment: Pretty sure you need the notification_key to remove the registration id? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/notifications#managing_device_groups