# How to retrieve group notification_key or delete existing group?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

Documentation is very poor concerning anything but the basic example and I cannot find how to retreive group notification_key or, alternatevly, delete a group using its notification_key_name and then create it again so that I could store its notification_key.

The reason I need this is that I forgot to store the notification_key the first time I created a group for a notification_key_name, for which I used a combination of app name and username. When I try to create a group with the same notification_key_name, I get a response that group already exists. I could probably change the key_name into something else (and in retrospect I should have used something like test-johndoe while testing), but it would be much better to somehow retreive the group key or just delete the entire group and create it again. How do I do that?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511764/user-notifications-how-to-recover-a-lost-notification-id-from-gcm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511764/user-notifications-how-to-recover-a-lost-notification-id-from-gcm)