# Deal with transitory errors when creating a gcm group and storing the notification_key

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I'm integrating gcm on the server side but I've found an unrecoverable issue while managing user groups. Consider the following workflow:

1. Create user group with notification_key_name = "userid"
2. GCM replies with the notification_key
3. Storing the notification_key in the database fails for some reason (even with retries)

Now if the overall process happens again:

1. Create user group with notification_key_name = "userid";
2. GCM replies with an error: "notification_key already exists"

As you see, the GCM create group operation is not idempotent. Because of this, this user group will be completely unusable since there's no way to retrieve its notification_key. Also, there's no way to delete a group or to empty it because its notification_key is not known in the second iteration.

Call me crazy, but when I'm developing I usually think about all the error situations in the code path.

Any suggestions about how to deal with the situation explained above?

Thanks

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26511764/user-notifications-how-to-recover-a-lost-notification-id-from-gcm